# Contracting a Tensor with a CTensor in xAct

Tags: tensors, xact

I'm trying to contract two tensors that I made in xAct to get a simple result. First I set up a Cartesian space

```
DefManifold[M, 3, {i, j, k, l, m, n}];
DefChart[ch, M, {1, 2, 3}, {x[], y[], z[]}, ChartColor -> Black];
met = CTensor[IdentityMatrix[3], {-ch, -ch}];
SetCMetric[met, ch, SignatureOfMetric -> {3, 0, 0}];

(*define a CTensor and a regular symmetric tensor*)
r = CTensor[{x[], y[], z[]}, {ch}];
DefTensor[S[-i, -j], M, Symmetric[{-i, -j}]]

S[i,j]r[-i]r[-j]
```

I expected $S_{11}x^2+\dots$ but it refuses to contract. How do I get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this question myself while asking it. I have not defined a co-ordinate system for $S$. Doing so requires converting to a CTensor

```
Sp = ToCTensor[S, {-ch, -ch}]
Sp[i,j]r[-i]r[-j]
```

works!